# ReactJS- Execute function while sending to child Component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am working on react LMS 
Enrolled Should send **true** or **false**. Based on if the user has already enrolled in that course. How to execute **CheckifEnrolled** function upon sending it to child.

````
 <CourseCard
                  Enrolled={()=>CheckIfEnrolled(Course.courseid)?true:false}
                  Course={Course}
                  UserInfoFromDB={props.UserInfoFromDB}
                  isSignedIn={props.isSignedIn}
                />```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing

```
()=>CheckIfEnrolled(Course.courseid)?true:false
```

that is an arrow function that when will be triggered will return some bool, pass

```
CheckIfEnrolled(Course.courseid)?true:false
```

now you are passing the bool itself accord the result of `CheckIfEnrolled`